# ASP.NET Azure project does not appear to load newest content items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC project and I am testing deployment to Windows Azure via the local emulator. I can run the project file fine in the development server but when I build the Azure project and it launches via the emulator I am having an issue with content files not being returned correctly. My internal CSS and JS files are being re-directed to the login page as if the authorization is failing; however I do not see where this auth requirement would be coming from.

Things I have already tried:

- I have manually removed all the build files from both project (I have also tried the "clean" action for the solution)
- I have tried removing the Azure project all together and creating a new one from the current version of my project.
- I have tried clearing the local storage through the Azure storage interface.
- I have verified that all my content is marked as "Content" in my ASP.NET project.
- I have tried flagging all of my content items as "Copy always"
- I have verified that the Static Content optional feature is checked

**EDIT:** I did a deploy to the web and everything works great there ... this is an emulator issue it appears. Any suggestions with that new bit of info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread has been open for a long time so I wanted to close it with what ended up being the solution.

It ended up being a bug with the emulator and the environment being used. As I mentioned, I was able to get it working when deployed. I actually tried this same situation 6 months later after updating to the latest Azure tool set and it worked fine so I am chalking this up to a bug in the emulator that has since been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify your web.config just to be sure. Do you see something like this?

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
...
</system.web>
```

Comment: Nope, I do not even have an authorization element in my Web.config

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the [Authorize] attribute on some of your controllers, or your controller base?

Comment: Nope none of my controllers but yes on a handful of actions. Also, I was able to get everything working fine when I published to the cloud, so this is an emulator only issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it works in the cloud and in ASP.NET Development Server, I am not very sure why it doesn’t work in emulator. However I don’t think the issue is related to your application. For now, I would like to suggest you to check your IIS settings, such as applicationHost.config. Please see if there’re any authorization settings that may cause this issue(Compute Emulator uses IIS under the hook to host web roles). Please also try to host the site in a local IIS directly and see if the same issue could be encountered. If you can reproduce this issue in IIS as well, I would recommend you to consider to add a “IIS” tag to this thread, so more IIS experts will provide further suggestions.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ming. I switched my project over to use IIS Express instead of the development server and everything appears to be working fine. Is this a good test for the situation your a pointing out?

Comment: Since IIS Express is still different with IIS. It would be better if you can try to deploy your solution to the full IIS locally to see whether the same issue could be encountered.

Comment: Thanks Ming I will give that a try and let you know what happens!